# MHZ19B Sensor - Library not found- Please Help!

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is here. I am trying to upload this code to Arduino Uno but it keeps telling me that the library is not found. I did download the library for the MHZ sensors but it doesn't like it.
I am somewhat new to Arduino.
Please help!
This is the code:

```
// Libraries
#include <DHT.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <MHZ19B.h>

// Constants
const int chipSelect = 10;   // SD card chip select pin
#define DHTPIN 7             // DHT sensor pin
#define DHTTYPE DHT22        // DHT sensor type
#define MHZ19B_TX_PIN 8      // MHZ19B sensor TX pin
#define MHZ19B_RX_PIN 9      // MHZ19B sensor RX pin

// Variables
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
File dataFile;

MHZ19B mhz19b;
float hum;      // Humidity value
float temp;     // Temperature value
int lightVal;   // Light sensor value
int co2;        // CO2 concentration

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();

  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("card initialized.");

  Serial.print("Initializing MHZ19B sensor...");
  mhz19b.begin(MHZ19B_TX_PIN, MHZ19B_RX_PIN);
  Serial.println("MHZ19B sensor initialized.");
}

void loop()
{
  lightVal = analogRead(A1);
  Serial.print("Light Value: ");
  Serial.println(lightVal);
  delay(50);

  hum = dht.readHumidity();
  temp = dht.readTemperature();
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(hum);
  Serial.print(" %, Temp: ");
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.println(" Celsius");
  delay(5);

  co2 = mhz19b.getCO2();
  Serial.print("CO2 Concentration: ");
  Serial.print(co2);
  Serial.println(" ppm");

  dataFile = SD.open("datalog.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  if (dataFile) {
    dataFile.println("Light Value: ");
    dataFile.println(lightVal);
    delay(50);

    hum = dht.readHumidity();
    temp = dht.readTemperature();
    dataFile.print("Humidity: ");
    dataFile.println(hum);
    dataFile.print(" %, Temp: ");
    dataFile.println(temp);
    dataFile.println(" Celsius");

    co2 = mhz19b.getCO2();
    dataFile.print("CO2 Concentration: ");
    dataFile.print(co2);
    dataFile.println(" ppm");

    delay(5000);
    dataFile.close();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Error opening datalog.txt");
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: look at the example code in the library

Answer (score 1):

That's because it should be either `#include <MHZ.h>` for the MH-Z CO2 Sensors library or `#include <MHZCO2.h>` for the MHZCO2 one.

How do you typically include the libraries you download? Thru the library manager? The way you can do it in Arduino IDE 2.0 is going  thru *Sketch* -> *Include Library* -> the library you want to include -- that should include the correct header.

Comment: Yes. The library manager. Thank you for your help. I will try this.

Comment: @Maria you're welcome! As jsotola mentions above, take a look at the example in the library (if you're going to use the MH-Z CO2 Sensors one) - the way the sensor is initialized is a bit different than how you've done it in the sketch you've provided.

Comment: Ok. I will take a look. I am not fluent with Arduino code but I will check and see if I can modify and make it work.